U-Boot on alternative pins
My GPIO 14/15 pins (and I believe UART0 and UART1) are broken, so I cannot use the default serial port for U-Boot.
How can I get U-Boot to boot on a different serial port on my Raspberry Pi 4B?

what does broken mean?

It means they fail gpiotest, among other tests I have done to determine that they do not function to read inputs or write outputs.
